# named database in Play and Squeryl test gave error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, squeryl

I followed [this link](http://www.artima.com/articles/play2_scala_squeryl.html) “Test the Model” part to write a test in `Play` and `Squeryl`. But I am using a named database "test" rather than "default". The following code does not work

```
import models.{AppDB, Bar}

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.inTransaction

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class BarSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {

  "A Bar" should "be creatable" in {
    running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("test"))) {
      inTransaction {
        val bar = AppDB.barTable insert Bar(Some("foo"))
        bar.id should not equal(0)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I got an error saying:

```
[info] BarSpec:
[info] A Bar 
[info] - should be creatable *** FAILED ***
[info]   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path ' - could not find datasource for default': Token not allowed in path expression: '-' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePathExpression(Parser.java:881)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePath(Parser.java:921)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Path.newPath(Path.java:206)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.hasPath(SimpleConfig.java:70)
[info]   at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:549)
[info]   at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$error(DB.scala:274)
[info]   at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$5.apply(DB.scala:413)
[info]   at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$5.apply(DB.scala:413)
[info]   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
[info]   at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.getDataSource(DB.scala:413)
[info]   ...
[error] Failed: : Total 5, Failed 3, Errors 0, Passed 2, Skipped 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     DataSourceTest
[error]     BarSpec
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tests unsuccessful
```

I guess I cannot directly use inTransaction here. But what should I do to make the test case pass when I use non-"default" database names?

Thank you.

Comment: What the f^&k does `playback` tag mean in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to setup connection for several databases for example:

```
package models

import org.squeryl.adapters.{H2Adapter}
import org.squeryl.Session
import play.api.Application
import play.api.db.DB


object TestConn {

  def test_session(app : Application) = Session.create( DB.getConnection("test")(app), new H2Adapter)

}
```

And then in you BarSpec:

```
 .....
    "A Bar" should "be creatable" in {
        running(FakeApplication()) {
          transaction(TestConn.test_session(current)){
            val bar = AppDB.barTable insert Bar(Some("foo"))
            bar.id should not equal(0)
          }
        }
      } 
   .....
```

Notice that you might have conf/evalutions/test directory with your database schema for these case.